# Cygwin: parsing whitespaced arguments using getopt

Tags: cygwin, getopt

I have a problem with a Cygwin script that uses getopt.  I am able to reproduce the problem with the following code snippet.

Basically I want to process some command line arguments using getopt.  My command line arguments have whitespace characters in them (spaces & tabs --- Windows filenames to be precise).  I am able to read all the command line arguments in the script correctly (including the whitespace characters) but when I use getopt and loop through all the arguments, one by one, Cygwin incorrectly treats each whitespace as an argument separator.

Pointers appreciated.

Note:- I have played with using quotes, where I deemed appropriate, but it did not help my cause.

```
# Command line arguments passed are as follows:
# »script«    -a "/A/B/C Directory/1.txt" -b "/A/B/D Directory/2.txt" -c "/A/B/E Directory/3.txt"

echo "Argument-1: " $1
echo "Argument-2: " $2
echo "Argument-3: " $3
echo "Argument-4: " $4
echo "Argument-5: " $5
echo "Argument-6: " $6

#
# So far no problems
#

echo
echo

set -- `getopt a:b:c: "$*"`

counter=1
while [ "$1" != "--" ]
do
  echo "getopt-$counter: " $1
  counter=$[$counter + 1]
  shift 1
done

#
# Now there's a problem. The six command line arguments (three with blank spaces) are incorrectly
# interpreted as nine command line arguments
#
```